Gyre Sage with Joraga Warcaller +1/+1 comprehension
I have a Gyre Sage with no counters on it in play and I play Joraga Warcaller multikicked 3 times. I get a +1/+1 counter on Gyre Sage because of the evolve and 3 +1/+1. The question is: How much mana does Gyre Sage produce with its activated ability?

Gyre Sage is a 1/2 without any modifications to its power or toughness.
When Joraga Warcaller enters the battlefield, kicked 3 times, it enters as a 4/4 creature. However, its third ability - "Other Elf creatures you control get +1/+1 for each +1/+1 counter on Joraga Warcaller" – immediately begins to apply as soon as it enters, so Gyre Sage immediately becomes a 4/5.
Because Joraga Warcaller has neither power nor toughness greater than Gyre Sage, its evolve ability will not trigger. It won't get a +1/+1 counter as a result of it entering.
Note that Joraga Warcaller does not place +1/+1 counters onto Gyre Sage - so Gyre Sage doesn't produce any additional mana as a result of this 'anthem' effect.

That's what I was thinking for the mana production. You have to separete the +1/+1 counters to the +1/+1. And thanks for the precision on the third ability I totaly missed that.
